# How to declare repositories in Gradle generated POMs

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle, pom.xml

I am publishing an artifact A to a self maintained maven repository on GitHub. The project has several transitive dependencies B, C, D which are hosted in different repositories. The dependencies B, C, D are specified in the gradle generated pom.xml (uploadArchives) of A but not the paths to the repositories. Therefore, the transitive dependencies B, C, D are not downloaded when A is specified as a dependency in another project.

Is it possible to tell gradle to include the urls of the maven repositories of B, C, D in the pom.xml of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is to customize the generated POM. Here is an example, assuming that the `maven` plugin is used for publishing:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            // add further information to the generated POM
            // syntax maps 1:1 to POM syntax
            pom.project {
                // could also generate this programmatically
                // based on the repos declared in the build
                repositories {
                    repository {
                        id 'myrepo'
                        url 'http//my.repo.com'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The new, incubating `maven-publish` plugin offers a similar hook.

Note that Gradle itself doesn't honor repositories declared in POMs when resolving dependencies, but only repositories declared by your build. Also check out http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to include the repositories for all transitive dependencies of A into the gradle build script of a program that depends on A? Many small open source projects are not available on maven central etc. but like my project on a private host (or github, bitbucket, etc.).

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. If A lives in a source code repository such as GitHub that's accessible via HTTP, it could provide a `repositories.gradle` containing the necessary repository declarations. Other builds could then include these declarations with `apply from: "http://path/to/repo/repositories.gradle"`.