# How can I make a transitive dependency in gradle also use the dependency's original source?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have a library, which I call `core`, which is a dependency of another project, called `Museum`. In `core`'s build.gradle, I am using `gson-fire`, which is specified as a dependency in the following manner:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/julman99/mvn-repo/master'}
}

...

dependencies {
 compile 'com.github.julman99:gson-fire:0.11.0'
}
```

This works fine - `core` is compiled. When I go to use it in my `Museum` project, though, I get the following:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':Museum'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Museum:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.github.julman99:gson-fire:0.11.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/jwir3/.m2/repository/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.pom
         file:/Users/jwir3/.m2/repository/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.jar
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.pom
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.jar
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/julman99/gson-fire/0.11.0/gson-fire-0.11.0.jar
     Required by:
         museum:Museum:unspecified > com.jwir3.core:core:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The `build.gradle` of `Museum` looks like the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.thisclicks.core:core:' + project.CORE_LIB_VERSION+ '+@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

Presumably, this is because the `core` library is specified as `transient = true` in the `build.gradle` of `Museum`, but it doesn't have the correct location to search for the Maven repository of `gson-fire`. Is there a way to make these search locations transient as well as the dependencies themselves?

Comment: For the record, another answer to a similar question: [How to declare repositories in Gradle generated POMs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17036916/413020), where [Peter Niederwieser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser) states that _Gradle itself doesn't honor repositories declared in POMs when resolving dependencies_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not automatically, no. Transitive dependencies do not bring in repository information, only the artifacts themselves. If you want this to work you'll have to add the `repositories { }` block from the `core` project to the `Museum` project.

Additionally, adding `transitive = true` is unnecessary in this case. This is the default anyway, and as explained above, is unrelated to this particular issue.